# How to repair a broken 2.4 GHz remote control?

Tags: microcontroller, rf, repair, remote-control

I have bought a [Remote Control Drifter Stunt Car (Z109S)](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Z109S-2-4G-RC-Lateral-Drift_62495422360.html). Unfortunately, part of the remote control has been broken. I tried to solder the broken path but still not works.

Is there any specification for remote control circuit or microcontroller model used that I can repair it?
Can I use another 2.4 GHz RC or it depends to the manufacture?

Here is the image of circuit:

[image]

Comment: Please post the model of the chips on the board or at least a picture where they can be identified from.

Comment: This is my question, unfortunately nothing is written on the chip and I put the picture and the car brand if someone can guess based on his experience. @Ralph

Comment: Ok good, I was unsure if it was intentionally blank or hidden by reflections.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are several cracks in that circuit board, with broken tracks.  Fixing it won't be simple.

You would need to trace all the broken tracks, to see where they go.  Once you have done that, the most practical option would be to solder fine wires on to replace the broken tracks, connecting the solder pads of the components each side of the break.

Answer (score 0):

With any luck the microcontroller (or what ever the IC is on the picture) is not damaged, if it has flexed enough from it's feet.

The cracks on the PCB cut many traces. You need to scrape some of the solder mask off with a hobby/surgical knife or such and fix the tracks with wire and solder. Using only solder to bridge connections might end up cracking the solder or pulling the tracks from the PCB, so best to leave some flexibility with a wire.

You also need to come up with a way to prevent the broken PCB from flexing to prevent damage to the IC. A rigid frame or flooding some epoxy to the backside where there are not components that might overheat from being blocked by epoxy.